# Django REST framework - "Method \"GET\" not allowed." -

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

In creating Django REST framework, i'll get all the data using this code

views.py

```
@api_view(['GET', ])
def api_detail_educationlevel(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        educationlevel = EducationLevel.objects.all()
        serializer = EducationLevelSerializer(educationlevel, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

urls.py

```
path('api/', views.api_detail_educationlevel),
```

but when i add in my views.py like this

```
@api_view(['PUT', ])
def api_update_educationlevel(request, pk):

    try:
        educationlevel = EducationLevel.objects.get(pk=pk)
    except EducationLevel.DoesNotExist:
        return HttpResponse(status=404)

    if request.method == 'PUT':
        serializer = EducationLevelSerializer(educationlevel, data=request.data)
        data = {}
        if serializer.is_valid():
          serializer.save()
          data["success"] = "update successfull"
          return Response(data=data)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)


@api_view(['DELETE', ])
def api_delete_educationlevel(request, pk):

    try:
        educationlevel = EducationLevel.objects.get(pk=pk)
    except EducationLevel.DoesNotExist:
        return HttpResponse(status=404)

    if request.method == 'DELETE':
        operation = educationlevel.delete()
        data ={}
        if operation:
          data["success"] = "delete successfull"
        else:
          data["failure"] = "delete failed"
        return Response(data=data)

@api_view(['POST', ])
def api_create_blog_view(request):
    authentication_classes = [SessionAuthentication, BasicAuthentication]
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]

    def get(self, request, format=None):
        content = {
            'user': unicode(request.user),  # `django.contrib.auth.User` instance.
            'auth': unicode(request.auth),  # None
        }
        return Response(content)
```

and in my urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
  path('api/', views.api_detail_educationlevel),
  path('api/update/', views.api_update_educationlevel),
  path('api/delete/', views.api_delete_educationlevel),
  path('api/create/', views.api_create_blog_view),
]
urlpatterns = format_suffix_patterns(urlpatterns)
```

I dont know why i am getting this message,

in my **path('api/update/', views.api_update_educationlevel),**

[image]

in my **path('api/delete/', views.api_delete_educationlevel),**

[image]

in my **path('api/create/', views.api_create_blog_view),**

[image]

any idea why i am getting this message? i just want functional rest framework that can update/delete/insert data using user auth account

Comment: You're prefixing your controller with, `@api_view(['PUT', ])` -- specifying that it should only respond to PUT calls. Why would it allow you to use GET on that endpoint?

Comment: what should i do? i just follow the documentation here https://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/3-class-based-views/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For each of these views (`views.api_detail_educationlevel, views.api_update_educationlevel, views.api_delete_educationlevel, views.api_create_blog_view`), you define `@api_view(['*api method*', ])`.

Only the `views.api_detail_educationlevel` has `@api_view(['GET', ])` therefore allowing a GET method. The others don't. Either add a GET method to the other views or, like the [documentation](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/3-class-based-views/) you follow, create a class containing each method.

Comment: Hi, Good day ! should i add 'GET' to my "" @api_view(['GET','DELETE']) "" ?

Comment: @justin You can, but I would suggest to write one class containing all methods. that's easier to maintain. see the documentation (https://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/3-class-based-views/)